# Local synonymous variable to non exact type

Tags: c, function, gcc, constants, typedef

I'm a little bit new to C so I'm not familiar with how I would approach a solution to this issue. As you read on, you will notice its not critical that I find a solution, but it sure would be nice for this application and future reference. :)

I have a parameter int hello and I wan't to make a synonomous copy of not it.

```
f(int hello, structType* otherParam){  
  // I would like to have a synonom for (!hello)
}
```

My first thought was to make a local constant, but I'm not sure if there will be additional memory consumption. I'm building with GCC and I really don't know if it would recognize a constant of a parameter (before any modifications) as just a synonymous variable. I don't think so because the parameter could (even though it wont be) changed later on in that function, which would not effect the constant.

I then thought about making a local typedef, but I'm not sure exactly the syntax for doing so. I attempted the following:

```
typedef (!hello) hi;
```

However I get the following error.

```
D:/src-dir/file.c: In function 'f':
D:/src-dir/file.c: 00: error: expected identifier or '(' before '!' token
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that I didn't expect the typedef to work that way in the first place. I figured it was a bit of a long shot... Would be cool to have a similar solution though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in C, you want to write the code that most clearly expresses your intentions, and allow the optimiser to figure out the most efficient way to implement that.

In your example of a frequently-reused calculation, storing the result in a `const`-qualified variable is the most appropriate way to do this - something like the following:

```
void f(int hello)
{  
    const int non_hello = !hello;

    /* code that uses non_hello frequently */
}
```

or more likely:

```
void x(structType *otherParam)
{  
    char * const d_name = otherParam->b->c->d->name;

    /* code that uses d_name frequently */}
}
```

Note that such a `const` variable does *not* necessarily have to be allocated any memory (unless you take its address with `&` somewhere) - the optimiser might simply place it in a register (and bear in mind that even if it *does* get allocated memory, it will likely be stack memory).

Comment: Well put. You seem to understand my intent quite clearly and reassured some of my haziness around const qualified memory allocations in regards to how a compiler 'might' handle its optimizations in a situation like mine. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Typedef defines an alias for a type, it's not what you want. So..

- **Just use `!hello` where you need it**

Why would you need a "synonym" for a `!hello` ? Any programmer would instantly recognize `!hello` instead of looking for your clever trick for defining a "synonym".

Comment: I was hoping my example would be obviously just an example. I will have a long list of accessors in this scenario, for several variables per function (many functions). This is also a performance critical application on an low memory device. I'm not opposed to additional parameters (the current way we're doing things), however I'm just asking to see if there was a better way.

Your solution is regrettably inadequate.

Comment: @Xoorath I challenge you to find a better solution, **performance-wise** :-) If you can do that, I challenge you to write an example where it shows.

Comment: @cnicutar Perhaps I'm worrying too much about a massive use of near-instantaneous operations. If we've got a list of 3-5 pointer accessors and a ! operator used about a dozen times in a function called a few hundred times per frame, do you think it would still be faster then adding another parameter per variable?

ie: 
f(a)
if(!a->b->c->d->e) //...
// as well as additional variables accessed down the chain from a

versus
f(a,b,c,d,e)
if(!e) ..//
// as well as usage of other parameters.

Comment: @Xoorath I don't know the constraints of your hardware. But usually memory is cheaper than time. Do you really lack the space for another variable ? Have you profiled this and found that using a separate integer versus writing `!original` will be faster ?

Comment: @cnicutar I'm unable to discus the constraints of my work. I'll just profile the options later if it becomes an issue. You're right, that is typically the case - and likely the case in what I'm doing now. If there was a way to create a synonym for what I was doing it could look as clean as the current solution with the (likely) performance benefit of your suggestion.

Well, unless I magically get an answer that lends itself to doing what I hoped (which isn't likely) I'll give you the check.

Comment: @Xoorath: C compilers do lots of optimizations. Also, ! will probably take 1 cycle, do the maths to see how many !'s yout CPU can do per frame.

Comment: @Xoorath: and _never_ optimize anything before measuring.

Comment: @Xoorath **You should unaccept my answer**; An accepted answer will deter possible posters. You likely need a good answer more than I need 15 rep.

Comment: @ninjalj This is less then a spot optimization as it is a design consideration. As mentioned, this example isn't true to my use case. Especially not true to my use case for the speed of the operations involved - the question I posed is to find out if it is possible to create local synonyms and not about my reasons for doing so or the performance benefits in doing so.

Comment: @Xoorath: so is it to avoid duplication? Then use an inline function.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
f(int hello, structType* otherParam){  
  // I would like to have a synonom for (!hello)
}
```

The obvious, direct answer to what you have here would be:

```
f(int hello, structType *otherParam) { 
    int hi = !hello;
    // ...
}
```

I would *not* expect to see any major (or probably even minor) effect on execution speed from this. Realistically, there probably isn't a lot of room for improvement in the execution speed.

There are certainly times something like this can make the code more readable. Also note, however, that when/if you modify the value of `hello`, the value of `hi` will *not* be modified to match (unless you add code to update it). It's rarely an issue, but something to remain aware of nonetheless.

Comment: This was what I was thinking with the const idea. const works for my situation, but obviously your answer doesn't assume that which is good. I'd say this is just as reasonable as the additional params. Do you know if passing parameters will add additional overhead past the memory consumption of the copy? I'll look into it as well, and comment my findings if nobody else has first.

Comment: Passing additional parameters normally takes (a little) extra time to put the parameters on the stack (or in the registers) to be accepted as parameters. The top page of the stack will almost always be in cache though, so the cost is normally *extremely* minimal.